# last in firstout div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement to add 5 divs one by one on each click of a div button (the new `div` should be added below the existing `div`). I've written some code, but the new `div`s are getting attached to the existing `div`.

Please help to correct this.

I have another button which removes the added `div`s one by one (new ones to be removed first).

Sorry if this is a lot of code; I'm new to jQuery and scripts.

[Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/YvE5F/3/).
script:

```
$("#dragbtnmore").click(function () {
        $('.toAdd').each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                $(this).css('display', 'block');
                return false;
            }
        });
        var i = 0;
        $('.toAdd').each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                i++;
            }
        });
        if (i == 5)
            $('#dragbtnmore').click(function () { return false; });
    });
    $("#dragbtnless").click(function () {
        $('.toAdd').each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
                $(this).css('display', 'none');
                return false;
            }
        });
        var i = 0;
        $('.toAdd').each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'block') {
                i++;
            }
        });
        if (i == 5)
            $('#dragbtnless').click(function () { return false; });
        $('#dragbtnless').click(function () { return true; });
    });

    function showmore() {
        document.getElementById('containershowmore').style.display = "block";
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="clearFix"></div>
     <div id="containershowmore" >
        <div id="dragbtnmore" style="cursor: default;">Show more buttons</div>
        <div id="dragbtnless" style="cursor: default;">Show Fewer buttons</div>
    </div>

 <div class="toAdd" style="display:none;" >
                <div id="dragdashboardmain" style="cursor: pointer;">dash</div></div>
    <div class="toAdd" style="display:none;" >
        <div id="dragrcalendar" style="cursor: pointer;">Calendar</div></div>
    <div class="toAdd" style="display:none;">
        <div id="dragresourcelist" style="cursor: pointer;">Rlist</div></div>
    <div class="toAdd" style="display:none;">
        <div id="dragdailynotes" style="cursor: pointer;">D Notes</div></div>
    <div class="toAdd" style="display:none;">
        <div id="dragweeklynotes" style="cursor: pointer;">W Notes</div></div>
```

style:

```
#containershowmore
{
position: relative;margin-left: 160px;background-color: #b1dafb;z-index: 1;
width: 125px;
    float:right;
padding-left: 5px;
}
#dragbtnmore{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.toAdd
{
height:20px;
    width:70px;

position: relative;
margin-bottom: 14px;

}
```

Comment: here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/YvE5F/3/

Comment: The code has to go **in the question**. It's not OK for your question to depend on off-site links to be answerable.

Comment: @meager I really dont understand what is the problem. I tried to create the easier way to understand my code. and I'm not the only one to use jsfiddle here in stackoverflow. Your reason is very dumb

Comment: I agree with @meagar. You should include the code in the answer because (1) it avoids link obsolescence (SO is not here to satisfy only the OP needs, but primarily for the community needs); (2) it raises your chances of getting an answer (I usually don't even try to answer a question where I have to browse links - especially on sites where they require me to install flash plug-ins or lower my browser defenses to see the code).

Comment: Stack Overflow **requires** your code to be included in the question. We have a vote-to-close reason specifically for questions that don't follow this rule.

Comment: I totally get your point. I copy pasted the fiddle code, Now it fits the rule as per your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this while removing the element.

```
 $('.toAdd :visible :last').hide();
        return false;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sudhAnsu63/xSq8G/)**

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sudhAnsu63/mNLN8/)**

Comment: It's one time run, Not working second time

Comment: try the updated one http://jsfiddle.net/sudhAnsu63/mNLN8/

Comment: Thankyou;BUT even while adding new buttons, need the newer ones get added on top of the old ones.

Comment: You can use **[append]** or **prepend** of any selector to add any element in specific location.
[append][http://api.jquery.com/append/]

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:-http://jsfiddle.net/YvE5F/5/

**JS:-**

```
//i need the output after click showmore buttons:
//w notes 
//d notes 
//R list 
//calendar 
// dash

// while removing need w notes to get removed first, 
// say like lastin firstout


$("#dragbtnmore").click(function () {
    $('.toAdd').each(function () {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).css('display', 'block');
            return false;
        }
    });
    var i = 0;
    $('.toAdd').each(function () {
        if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
            i++;
        }
    });
    if (i == 5) $('#dragbtnmore').click(function () {
        return false;
    });
});
$("#dragbtnless").click(function () {
    $($('.toAdd').get().reverse()).each(function () {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
            return false;
        }
    });
    var i = 0;
    $('.toAdd').each(function () {
        if ($(this).css('display') != 'block') {
            i++;
        }
    });
    if (i == 5) $('#dragbtnless').click(function () {
        return false;
    });
    $('#dragbtnless').click(function () {
        return true;
    });
});

function showmore() {
    document.getElementById('containershowmore').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thankyou;BUT even while adding i need the first in buttons to get added on top of the old ones.